# With Nunit, how to test if a method has caught an exception?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit

I have a method to save data in my database (C# and Mysql). I'm using the MVP model, so what it does is Save in Presenter > Save in Service > Save in manager > Save in dao. I do the data integrity control in the manager.

I want to test my presenter. The first save test is done with incorrect values to check if my manager throws an exception. 
The problem is that my presenter catch this exception, so I can't use the `Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => {DoSave();})` because the exception is not seen by the Assert.
Is there an Assert in NUnit to check if an exception has been raised within the tested code without reaching the test itself?

Simplified, it looks like that :
(Presenter)

```
    private void SaveData()
    {
            try
            {
                //Calls service who calls manager who checks data then call DAO to save.
                if (MyService.SaveData(currentData, ReferentielType.ENEG))
                {
                    //Success
                }
                else
                {
                    //Failure
                }
            }
            //Thrown by the manager if the data are incorrect
            catch (DataInvalidException ex)
            {
                // log exception as error
                TraceHelper.TraceError(ex, "The data {0} is not correct", currentData.Code);

                // send a message to user
                MessageContainer.Instance.SendErrorMessage("DataInvalid", BusinessError.DataInvalid, currentData.Code);
            }
        }
    }
```

And my test :

```
[Test]
    public void UpdateDataTest()
    {
        //Test setup 
        //making fake data
        //When the var etatDuTest is different from 0, it means some of the data are invalid

        //Instance of the presenter
        MockView view = new MockView();
        PresenterToTest presenter = new PresenterToTest(view);

        //Testing with invalid values
        //bad label
        ((MockView)((IView)presenter.View)).etatDuTest = 1;
        Assert.Throws<DataInvalidException>(() => { ((MockView)((IView)presenter.View)).RaiseSaveDataClicked(); });
        //Bad num eva
        ((MockView)((IView)presenter.View)).etatDuTest = 2;
        Assert.Throws<DataInvalidException>(() => { ((MockView)((IView)presenter.View)).RaiseSaveDataClicked(); });

        //Testing with everything OK
        //Tout est bon logiquement.
        ((MockView)((IView)presenter.View)).etatDuTest = 0;
        ((MockView)((IView)presenter.View)).RaiseSaveDataClicked();

    }
```

Comment: Is the line `MyService.SaveData(currentData, ReferentielType.ENEG)` which can throw an `Exception`?

Comment: Instead of asserting that the exception has been raised (which you won't be able to check) you should be making sure that when there is a `CoclicoInvalidException` in your `Presenter` class and that the `TraceError` and `MessageContainter` are being called correctly. To make sure that the `Manager` correctly throws an exception this should have it's own test class where the exception won't be handled within your business logic.

Comment: @StephenRoss yeah, I already wrote the manager test, but I wanted to test another layer of my app just to make sure the exception is caught.

Comment: So a workaround could be to test that `MyService.SaveData(currentData, ReferentielType.ENEG)` throws a `ColicoInvalidException` and then to test that `SaveData` does not throw it. Obviously using the same parameters. Note that this is not really a clean solution. This could be cleaner using a `delegate`

Comment: @nivolas in that case as I say you want to make sure that the `TraceHelper.TraceError` is called correctly with the appropriate arguments. And also that the `MessageContainer.Instance.SendErrorMessage` is correctly called with the appropriate arguments. This is to test that you have handled the exception correctly, you don't need to check within the test that it has been thrown as you will be verifying (or asserting) that your objects have been called correctly (depending on how you mock them).

Comment: @StephenRoss Sadly I'll have to do it that way, it's way harder than calling an Assert.throws and I'm already scrathing my head to know how I'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: @ZwoRmi So for that I guess I'd have to call the save twice otherwise I don't see how I can test that my service is raising an exception

Comment: Yes, in your test method you make a first call to `MyService.SaveData(currentData, ReferentielType.ENEG)` and assert that it is throwing an `Exception` and a second call to `SaveData()`, expecting that no Exception is thrown.

Comment: @nivolas I think the issue that you have is that `TraceHelper` and `MessageContainer` are both static classes. I would seriously think about changing these to an instanced class which is injected into your `Presenter` class. This means that you could interface the class and use a mocking testing framework like Moq to mock the interface. This would easily allow you to make verify that methods on these interfaces were called quickly and easily. Static classes are notoriously difficult to test and I think you've just hit the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing that an exception has been caught is by itself a pointless test. You should be testing what happens within the catch block, that will verify that the exception was caught.

If you can verify that your MessageContainer.Instance has that DataInvalid error message, that's your best option really.

Comment: I didn't think of the MessageContainer because I was focused on catching the  exception itelsf, but you're right.
As for testing a caught exception, I find it useful because it allows you to be sure that none has modified the data integrity control for his needs (since it's a method called by several presenters, it could be modified and we don't want that, it's a non-regression test more than a unit test)

Comment: Like I said, testing that the exception is caught is pointless, what you really care about is that when an exception is thrown by SaveData it executes the behaviour in the catch. That could be rewritten by anyone, but as long as it still executes that behaviour once an exception is thrown by SaveData you don't need to worry. You can't stop people rewriting code by writing tests for it, in fact that isnt the purpose of tests at all. They're there to ensure that people CAN change the method, but to ensure that no matter what, when SaveData throws an exception Instance.SendErrorMessage is called

Comment: The way I see it (I may be wrong but that's how I see my test)  is that if someone removes the control or changes it (Say someone change the string length control from 6 to 8 characters), the save may work or may throw another exception, so the test will fail. And in the end that's what I want, being aware of when the test fail to check why and decide what to do (change my test or change the integrity control)